# Copy block constants into module

Tags: ruby, module, dsl

I am trying to define a DSL where some constants are defined within a block and must be copied into a fresh made module. I got this so far:

```
class Foo
  def self.macros(&block)
    mod = Module.new do
      module_eval &block
    end
    self.const_set(:Macros, mod)
  end

  macros do
    Point = Struct.new :x, :y
    VALUE = 5

    def self.bar 
      "bar"
    end

    def foo
      "foo"
    end
  end
end
```

With the code above I managed to get `Foo::Macros.bar` however the constants are missing.

How can I get the constants defined within the block?

I want to access them through the new module embedded inside the class, like `Foo::Macros::Point`

Comment: As a note, constants are typically `ALL_CAPS` where classes and modules are `MixedCase`.

Comment: just updated the example. Also noticed that cannot get Struct or Classes initialized inside the Module either. The only thing that seems to be evaluated within the module are the function definitions

Comment: You may have trouble with this approach, declaring constants within blocks is highly irregular. I'd be inclined to spell it out more specifically with `const_set` or find an approach that doesn't involve using constants at all, instead declaring methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby constant lookup rules doesn't change with `class_eval` or `module_eval`, so you cannot make a constant defined in a block in `Foo` be part of `Foo::Macros`, sadly.

---

Simply:

```
Foo::Value
Foo::Point
```

`Foo::Macros` is just an alias for the anonymous module you defined, it doesn't change the scope of object defined.

If you define the module first, you can access it using `const_get`:

```
module Test
end
Test.module_eval do
  ANSWER = 42
end
Test.const_get('ANSWER')
=> 42
```

Comment: Ah! So there they are. But actually since I evaluated inside the Module.new I expected the constants be inside the module, not to be included into my class. Is that possible? Something like Foo::Macros::Point

Comment: Try to first define Foo::Macros then module_eval the block inside it, it should work

Comment: I tried your code inside the function and got an error about `dynamic constant assignment` Outside a class function works, but I still want the DSL to pack those constants inside a new module. Here are the things I tried so far: https://gist.github.com/fgarcia/0f566ea9313794e19db0

Comment: I edited my post with some info. I think this is not possible for constants